# Need help to implement User Signup in Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

This is the first time I am working with redux saga. I have a backend route called `https://localhost:5000/developers/signup`. I have a signup form:

```js
import { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';
import HttpService from 'services/Http';

export default function Signup() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '' });

    const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const httpService = new HttpService('api/developers/signup');
            const res = await httpService.create(formData);

            // I receive the user data + JWT token
            console.log(res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <main>
            <h1>Signup</h1>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                // Some JSX to show the form
            </form>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import authReducer from './ducks/auth';
import rootSaga from './sagas/root';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
});

const sagas = createSagaMiddleware();

const composeSetup =
    /*@ts-ignore eslint-disable  */
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        ? /*@ts-ignore eslint-disable  */
          window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        : compose;
/*eslint-enable */

const middleWare = [sagas];

const store = createStore(reducers, composeSetup(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)));

sagas.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

I am unable to understand what redux saga does, It would be great if someone could explain this. I've seen a lot of posts and youtube video. I looked at the docs but then it did not have a basic AJAX example. I would like to have a redux state structure like this:

```json
{
  auth: {
    // Some auth data like the token & user details
  }
}
```

Also, I am using functional components, so It would be great if your solution is compatible with that. Looking forward to talking, thanks in advance!

Comment: you can move your api call into redux worker function and `call(signupSuccessAction(res.data)` to dispatch payload to your reducer

Comment: Ok... could you share an answer with the code?

Answer (score 0):

you should create action to send data to the server

and use the action in your function

```
const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        dispatch(sendDataForSignup(e))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit fire an action with form data

```
import { signUp } from "actions";

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  signUp(formData);
};
```

which will forward the type and payload to watcher

```
export const signUp = (payload) => ({
  type: "SIGNUP_REQUEST",
  payload
});
```

the watcher will take the latest action and pass it to worker function that will make the api call and dispatch an action with response type and data

```
import { put, takeLatest, all } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* signupWorker() {
  const json = yield fetch("URL/signup").then((response) => response.json());
  yield put({ type: "SIGNUP_SUCCESS", json: json.data });
}
function* signupWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest("SIGNUP_REQUEST", signupWorker);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([signupWatcher()]);
}
```

and the reducer will handle the data as you like based on the types

```
const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGNUP_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "SIGNUP_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, ...action.payload, loading: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I tried this but I don't see any action being fired in the dev tools. Also, why are you not using the dispatch hook to dispatch the action?

Comment: I added console.logs to the watcher and the worker but then it is never executed